# Consistent rate of fire in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to give my guns fire rates that aren't affected by the frame rate.
Here's what my demo for this looks like:

```
public class testing : MonoBehaviour {

    private float nextFire;
    public int timer;

    void FixedUpdate () {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && Time.time > nextFire)
        {
            nextFire = Time.time + 0.1f;
            ++timer;
        }
    }

}
```

This fires approximately 180 shots in 20 seconds. I would think `+0.1f` would give me 200 shots, at least that's what I'm aiming for. Using `+0.0333f` fires around 500 shots, while I was expecting 600 shots.

This approach is [suggested](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/32frjx/gun_firerate_limited_by_framerate/) in most [sources](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/shooting-shots) I've found online, so I suspect it's the right one, but why can't I get a consistent rate of fire? Is it even possible?

Comment: Lets say one of your frames is off by 25ms, you are not compensating for that in any way, instead you wait another 100ms for the next round of fire.

Comment: Any chance you could point me in the right direction on how to do it properly?

Comment: Try nextFire += 0.1f; instead